# Delete keymap and completely disable key in zsh

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to disable <kbd>Insert</kbd> key completly in zsh. This key has no real use, and only annoys me when I hit it accidentally.

I found how to remove the binding for `overwrite-mode`

```
bindkey -r "^[[2~"
```

But now, when I actually hit <kbd>Insert</kbd>, instead of activationg overwrite-mode, it prints `~` on the cursor position.

Similar thing happens when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, which is not bound to anything. It also prints `~`.

How can I disable the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key completely (and <kbd>F12</kbd>, as well), so that pressing it does not do anything in zsh?

I don't want to disable <kbd>Insert</kbd> key globally, because some other programs may actually use it for useful purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press a special key (such as <kbd>Insert</kbd>) which sends an escape sequence that is not recognized by `zsh`, it will do this. zsh will try to do something with the individual bytes of the escape sequence.

Looking at the result from `bindkey`, it seems that zsh has no suitable function which can be bound to a key to *ignore* it.  But you could rebind <kbd>Insert</kbd> to an empty macro:

```
bindkey -s '\e[2~' ''
```

Likewise for <kbd>F12</kbd>. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd> to see what escape sequence <kbd>F12</kbd> sends, typically

```
bindkey -s '\e[24~' ''
```

According to the `zshzle` manual page, there is a limitation with this approach:

> As well as ZLE commands, key sequences can be bound to  other  strings, by  using  `bindkey -s'.  When such a sequence is read, the replacement string is pushed back as input, and the command reading process  starts again  using  these fake keystrokes.  This input can itself invoke urther replacement strings, but in order to detect loops the process will be stopped if there are **twenty** such replacements without a real command being read.

Binding to `\a` as I originally suggested does not appear to have this drawback, i.e.,

```
bindkey -s '\e[2~' '\a'
```

Comment: There is something funny happening, when I rebind the `insert` or `F12` keys. When I press the rebound key 20 times in a row, I get an error: "zsh: string inserting another one too many times".